# str::find always return 1 even if the value is not present in the array in cpp

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    const char* plating[8] = { "Agsdf","AgNsdfi","CuAsdfg","Nsdfi","NsdfiAg","NiPsdfd","Nonsfe","Psfd" };
    bool press = false;
    press = std::find(begin(plating),end(plating),"88love");
    cout<<press<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**
OutPut :- 1
**

**
Accepted Output :- 0
**

Comment: please use only language tags which are related to your question

Comment: tip: tagging 4 completely different languages is the best way to collect downvotes

Comment: `std::find` returns an iterator. Assigning that iterator to a bool doesn't really make sense.

Comment: more tip: read some documentation. Without that its no surprise that your expectations deviate from the actual output

Comment: In addition, you compare pointers, not string content...

Answer (score 2):

`std::find` does not return `1`. `press` is not `1` either. What happens is that `std::find` returns an iterator, which in your case is just a pointer. A pointer converted to a `bool` is `true` unless it is `nullptr`. When printing that `true` you get `1` in the output.

The right way to use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is to compare the returned iterator to `end(plating)` to know if the string was found. However, your are comparing pointers and even if you call find with a string that is in the array you do not necessarily get the right result.

Instead you should use `std::string`:

```
std::vector<std::string> plating = {" ..." ,"..."};
std::string needle{"88love"};
if ( std::find(plating.begin(),plating.end(),needle) == plating.end()) {
    std::cout << needle << " was not found! \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `std::find()` does not find the element it returns an iteretor to `last`. Therefore changing `press = std::find(begin(plating),end(plating),"88love");` to `press = std::find(begin(plating),end(plating),"88love")!=last(plating);` should solve your problem.
The way you try to do it the iterator is cast to a `bool`, which will be `true` if the returned iterator points to `last`.